# Test Method In Class which receives input from user via GetPass

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have the following method in a class, that I am attempting to write a unit test for:

```
from getpass import getpass

class GetInfo:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name

    def get_values(self):
        if self._name == 'Bob':
            phrase = getpass('What is your secret:')
            new_dict = {self._name: phrase}
        return new_dict
```

How would I write a unit test to verify the get_values method is functioning correctly? The piece I am most hung up on is how to mock the getpass value from the user. Thus far, this is what I have been able to write:

```
from getpass import getpass
from unittest.mock import patch

import mock
class TestInfo:
    @mock.patch("getpass.getpass")
    def test_get_credentials(self, password):
        password.return_value = 'Password1'
        info = GetInfo()
        output_dict = info.get_values()
        self.assertEqual(output_dict, {'Bob': 'Password1'})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_main()
```

However; currently I am receiving an EOFError, signaling that I probably am not passing the value to the function at all.
Would anyone be able to lend any insight?

Comment: How do you mock other functions that get user input? Wouldn't this be the same?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47690020/python-3-unit-tests-with-user-input

Comment: Thanks for linking that issue above, since I have a class I need to instantiate, how would i deal with the "module_under_test" value? Would this be the class instantiated with the method or just the class? I tried both ways and can't seem to get it to work.